Proving a matrix multivariable result from Freedman's "Statistical models"
It is given that $X$ is $n\times p$ with rank $p < n$. $Y$ is $n \times 1$. $\hat\beta=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$ and $e=Y-X\hat\beta$. He asks us to show that if $\gamma$ is $p\times 1$, then, $$||Y-X\gamma||^2=||Y-X\hat\beta||^2 + ||X(\hat\beta-\gamma)||^2 \tag a$$
Following the hint, I have proceeded thus: $$||Y-X\gamma||^2=||Y-X\hat\beta + X(\hat\beta-\gamma)||^2\tag b$$ Previously, it has been shown that $Y-X\hat\beta \perp X\hat\beta\tag c. $
So, in expanding rhs of $(b)$, I have $$\langle Y-X\hat\beta + X(\hat\beta-\gamma),Y-X\hat\beta + X(\hat\beta-\gamma)\rangle =||Y-X\hat\beta||^2 + ||X(\hat\beta-\gamma)||^2 + \mbox{cross term}$$ where, $$\mbox{cross term}=2 \langle Y-X\hat\beta,X(\hat\beta-\gamma)\rangle$$ Despite using $(c)$ this cross term does not vanish though. I still have remaining $-2\langle Y-X\hat\beta,X\gamma\rangle$ and it is not clear to me how I can work with this to prove $(a)$.

The approach is to use the property of orthogonal projections.
Note $\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}:=\mathbf X\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}=\mathbf P\mathbf Y, $ where $\mathbf P$ is the orthogonal projection matrix onto $\mathcal C(\mathbf X), $ the column space corresponding to $\mathbf X. $ Denoting $\boldsymbol \theta:=\mathbf X\boldsymbol\gamma, $ since $\boldsymbol\theta\in\mathcal C(\mathbf X), $ this means $\mathbf P\boldsymbol\theta=\boldsymbol \theta.$
Now the cross-product is $$\left(\mathbf Y-\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}\right) ^\top\left(\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}-\boldsymbol\theta\right)=\mathbf Y^\top\left(\mathbf I-\mathbf P\right) \mathbf P\left(\mathbf Y-\boldsymbol\theta\right)$$ which can be easily seen to yield zero.
--
Reference:
Linear Regression Analysis, George A. F. Seber, Alan J. Lee, John Wiley & Sons, $2003,$ sec. $3.1,$ p. $37.$
